# MVC Model properties are null when calling post mvc action via ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have below lines of code in controller, model and in js file.
I am able to make call to controller, but model properties are always null.
...

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateBooking(Country request)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

public class Country
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

var request = {
name: 'Prateek',
code: 'US'
};

```
$.ajax('/Home/CreateBooking', {
        data: JSON.stringify({ request }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {},
error: function(response){}
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't use `JSON.stringify`, use `data: request` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var request = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "Name": "Prateek", "Code": "US" }');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/CreateBooking",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: request,
        success: function (d) {
        },
        error: function (d) {
            console.log(d);
        }
    });
```